function does not satisfy PDE
I have a PDE like: $u_t + a(x-2)u_x = b(x-2)u$ and the initial condition: $u(0,x) = x^{k}$. By using the characteristics curves, I have:
$\frac{dt}{ds} = 1$ with IC: $t(0, \tau) = 0$
$\frac{dx}{ds} = a(x-2)$ with IC: $x(0, \tau) = \tau$
$\frac{du}{ds} = b(x-2)$ with IC: $u(0, \tau) = \tau^{k}$
Thus, after some basic algebra and taking the integrals I have:
$t = s$
$ln|x-2| = as + C \rightarrow x = \pm e^{as} e^C + 2$. Using the IC and $t = s$, I get $x = (\tau - 2)e^{as} + 2 \rightarrow \tau = \frac{x-2}{e^{at}} + 2$
Similarly, $ln|u| = b(x-2)s + C_2 \rightarrow u = \pm e^{b(x-2)s}e^{C_2}$. Using the IC to find $C_2$ and substituting $\tau$, I get $u(t,x) = (x-2+e^{at})^{k} e^{b(x-2)t-atk}$.
This $u$ does not satistfy the PDE but I see no issue with my solution except the initial conditions. I'd highly appreciate if you can point out the mistake. I also did the general solution and got the right form of $u$ thats satisfies the PDE which is $u = e^{g(ln|x-2|-at)}e^{bx/a}$.

Let's first correct a typo: the differential equation satisfied by $u(s)$ is
$$
\frac{du}{ds}=b(x-2)\color{red}{u}. \tag{1}
$$
You solved it treating $x$ as a constant. This is incorrect, since $x$ is a function of $s$. To solve it, either you replace $x$ on the RHS of $(1)$ with $x(s)=(\tau-2)e^{as}+2$, or take a shortcut, using the fact that $x-2=\frac{1}{a}\frac{dx}{ds}.$ Following the second alternative, we have
$$
\frac{du}{ds}=\frac{b}{a}\frac{dx}{ds}u
\implies \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{b}{a}u
\implies u=Ce^{bx/a}. \tag{2}
$$
From the conditions $x(0,\tau)=\tau$ and $u(0,\tau)=\tau^k$, it follows that
$C=\tau^ke^{-b\tau/a},$ hence
$$
u=\tau^{k}e^{b(x-\tau)/a}. \tag{3}
$$
Finally, substituting $\tau=(x-2)e^{-at}+2$ in $(3)$, we obtain
$$
u(t,x)=\left[(x-2)e^{-at}+2\right]^k\exp\left[\frac{b}{a}(x-2)(1-e^{-at})\right]. \tag{4}
$$

Let's check the solution:
\begin{align}
u_t&=-ka(x-2)e^{-at}\left[(x-2)e^{-at}+2\right]^{k-1}\exp\left[\frac{b}{a}(x-2)(1-e^{-at})\right] \\
&\phantom{= }+\left[(x-2)e^{-at}+2\right]^{k}\,b(x-2)e^{-at}\exp\left[\frac{b}{a}(x-2)(1-e^{-at})\right], \tag{5} \\
u_x&=ke^{-at}\left[(x-2)e^{-at}+2\right]^{k-1}\exp\left[\frac{b}{a}(x-2)(1-e^{-at})\right] \\
&\phantom{= }+\left[(x-2)e^{-at}+2\right]^{k}\,\frac{b}{a}(1-e^{-at})\exp\left[\frac{b}{a}(x-2)(1-e^{-at})\right], \tag{6}
\end{align}
hence
\begin{align}
u_t+a(x-2)u_x&=\left[-ka(x-2)e^{-at}+a(x-2)ke^{-at}\right] \\
&\qquad\qquad\times\left[(x-2)e^{-at}+2\right]^{k-1}\exp\left[\frac{b}{a}(x-2)(1-e^{-at})\right] \\
&\phantom{= }+\left[(x-2)e^{-at}+2\right]^{k}\left[b(x-2)e^{-at}+a(x-2)\frac{b}{a}(1-e^{-at})\right] \\
&\qquad\qquad\times\exp\left[\frac{b}{a}(x-2)(1-e^{-at})\right] \\
&=\left[(x-2)e^{-at}+2\right]^{k}\,b(x-2)\exp\left[\frac{b}{a}(x-2)(1-e^{-at})\right] \\
&=b(x-2)u. \quad{\square}\tag{7}
\end{align}

Thank you for pointing out the mistake, @gonçalo! However, the verification did not pass. When I solved for u_x, I got two terms, one of which is b(x-1)u aka RHS. But the remaining terms from u_t and u_x didn't cancel out each other.

Please check the addendum to my answer.

Thank you. I just did it myself and got it passed too. I made some mistakes as there are too many exponents. Really appreciated your help!
